# Generating word documents with image using PHP

Tags: php, ms-word, yii2

I'm trying to generate a ms-word document with image using Yii2.
My problem is that the final file does not contain a picture, but a link to it. And in the file, as a result, an error about the inability to display the picture

```
    $content = $this->render('export_word', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
    header("Content-Type: application/msword");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; 
    filename=filename.doc");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    print_r($content); exit;
```

view:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="photo"><img src="<?= $file?>"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And how do you actually generate the content for the document? I think this should be included in your question.

Comment: content it's a simple html

Comment: I'm not expert in this but looks like while Word can accept documents built like that, it's not perfect obviously. I recommend using 3rd party library that is made for that purpose like https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord